# How to scan text for multiple strings in php

Tags: php, string

In php, how do you scan text (in the form of user submitted messages) for multiple strings (in the form of other user names)?

Example, below a user submits a message, I want a way to "find" the strings 'user-one' and 'user-two' and send those strings into an array.

> Hello this is a test message, can you see it @user-one, @user-two?

Comment: Did you search at all on what PHP can offer?  You should look at [String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) or [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: Take a look at PHP's [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('|\@(.*) |' , $userText , $match);

print_r($match[1])
```

`$match[1]` will contain all usernames. `$userText` is the users input text. Use `$match[0]` if you want usernames with the `@`.

Comment: Thanks navnav. Ironic that I just noticed that posting this comment also involves the same functionality I was asking about! :)

Comment: You're welcome xD If this or any other answer was what you needed, be sure to mark it as correct (by clicking the green tick next to it).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the tip! I'd vote it up too, but I don't have the points to do so, so thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$message = "Hello this is a test message, can you see it @user-one, @user-two?" ;
preg_match_all("/\@[a-z\-]+/", $message,$match);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '@user-one' (length=9)
  1 => string '@user-two' (length=9)
```

Comment: I'd add word boundaries to prevent this from matching email addresses, and possibly make it case insensitive, depending on the OP's requirements. Other than that, looks good - +1.

Comment: Thanks .... good comments form the regex master himself .. can you do the honors of updating the question with the best approach .. thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, by word boundaries, am I right in assuming you mean a consistant 'end' character, for eg:
@user-one@ @otheruser2@

If so, would love to see an example in the regex.

Comment: @Competitions what nickC is referring to is different .. wordboundy is actually `\b` it used so that your regex would match `@user-tree` and not `wrong@user-tree` see Example 2 http://www.php.net/function.preg-match#refsect1-function.preg-match-examples

Comment: Thanks Baba, @nickb. Ironic that I just noticed that posting this comment also involves the same functionality I was asking about! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strrpos to retrieve a position and substr + strlen to get the text.
Example:

```
...
$mystring = "Hello this is a test message, can you see it @user-one, @user-two?";
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "@user-one");
if ($pos > 0) {
    $str = substr($mystring, $pos, strlen("@user-one"));
}
...
```

Sorry if I don't understand correctly the question.

Answer (score 0):

No messy pattern match with this!

```
function stringToUserArray($str) { 
$remove = array(".",",","!","?");
$str = str_replace($remove, " ", $str);
$array = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($array as $string) { 
    if($string[0] == "@") { 
        $users[] = $string;
    }
}

return $users;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. Ironic that I just noticed that posting this comment also involves the same functionality I was asking about! :)